# hybris Cache is not alive error

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am using hybris version 5.5.1, I have done modulegen and done all the configuration in localextention.xml, now when I started the hybris server (. ./hybrisserver.sh) and getting the below error.

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [DeploymentMigrationUtil] Error while migrating deployments of extension core
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The queryCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4075)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2766)
```

Comment: Can you add "installed.tenants=" on local.properties file and restart server again?

Comment: Please share the entire stacktrace. This could be due to multiple reasons.

Comment: @Vikrant https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2MjneaKlTS-81Fjqq-cUjcWHb3P_pv0MuOUhf0cEP4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the snippet below, this is taken from the stacktrace that you shared.

```
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [my.bookstore.cockpits.setup.CockpitSystemSetup] for bean with name 'yAcceleratorCockpitsSystemSetup' defined in org.springframework.integration.security.config.SecurityIntegrationConfigurationInitializer@4091564b; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.bookstore.cockpits.setup.CockpitSystemSetup**
at org.springframework.integration.security.config.SecurityIntegrationConfigurationInitializer.initialize(SecurityIntegrationConfigurationInitializer.java:63)
at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:48)
... 29 more 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.bookstore.cockpits.setup.CockpitSystemSetup
```

Now, please check for this bean initialization in your spring context, due to  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.bookstore.cockpits.setup.CockpitSystemSetup`

Look for the bean initialization where the bean injection of this class is declared, and make sure that the qualified name of the class is correct.

Let me know if the issue still persists.